# Can "limber up" be used as "activity to reduce stiffness" without the part about "further exertion"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

`limber up` is defined as light activities to prepare for serious physical effort [[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/limber-up),[2](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/limber+up),[3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/limber-up),[4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limber%20up)].
From what I've seen, `limber up` is defined just as `make more flexible` only in [one](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/limber+up) dictionary.

Therefore I'd like to clarify: Is it fine to use `limber up` for the situation when a person eliminates stiffness in the muscles after some actions? I'm talking about the case where no further physical effort is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess ***limbering up*** is more often used ***metaphorically*** than literally today (the *literal* sense is usually expressed by ***warming up*** nowadays).

But to my mind, both ***limber up*** and ***warm up*** strongly imply "in preparation for further exertion". If we're just talking about a situation where you need to ease stiff muscles, use ***loosen up*** - or in many contexts, just ***stretch*** (your arms and/or legs).